# PHP Relative Pathing

Tags: php

I have constructed a simple, beginner level PHP website that i have been instructed to:

```
use relative paths for any links in your assignment – I should not need to deploy
your assignment into the same folder structure that you developed it in when marking
```

But i don't quite understand what this means, to my knowledge all ive done is placed all my files in :

```
XAMPP\htdocs\WebsiteFolder
```

WebsiteFolder being the root of the assignment, and links in my files are only ever shown like these examples:

```
header('Location: somephpfile.php')
<a href="somephpfile.php">Click Me</a>
```

Am i on the right track here with what has been asked of me?

Comment: Yes, those are relative paths. http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be on a right track. A relative link is a link that relates to root directory.

In your case `XAMPP\htdocs\WebsiteFolder` appears to be the root directory, say that you have `images` and `styles` directories, and `index.php` file in it, relative paths in `index.php` would look as follows:

`./images/house.png`

While a relative path to the same file from a CSS file in `styles` directory would look like:

`../images/house.png`

Where `.` means *current directory* and `..` means *parent directory*.

This way links do not require editing when the whole project directory is moved to another place on hard drive or onto another computer.